# Solution for adding sub-grid to entity in CRM 2011 for relationship that is not customizable

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to add a sub-grid to the Price List entity for Price List Items.  When looking at the dropdown list of options for entities in the insert sub-grid dialog I do not see Price List Items as an option.  After further investigation it appears that the only options in the list are 1:N relationships that are set as customizable, which Price List Items are not.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Is this a Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise deployment? Also, do you have a view ID for any Price List Items views?

Answer (score 0):

I'd asked about the viewID because in the FormXml for the "main" form, you can find a section that details how the subgrid for the products associated with the `pricelevel` (Price List) is constructed, and the principal parameter there is the `ViewId`, which is the system view id of the entity you're interested in viewing/editing.

I asked about the type of deployment (on-premise vs. online) because you can just look at the database in the `SavedQuery` table to get the `ViewID` for `productpricelevel` (price level detail), but I'm sure you can get this by a normal CRM query as well. Anyway, the ViewID that I have on record for the "All Price List Items" view is "AB4877E9-6D01-4D28-84C3-BE7564C1BB09", and I'm betting it's the same for your organization.

With this information, you can modify the FormXml for `pricelevel` and add in the subgrid XML for `productpricelevel` as shown below. If you need to modify the layout of the UI, you can look at another entity that has the layout you want and modify appropriately.

```xml
<row>
  <!--cell id: a distinct GUID for this area of the form. Any will do.-->
  <cell id="{74e711eb-0eec-119e-8703-ce8b5dbbca94}" showlabel="true" colspan="1" auto="false" rowspan="8">
    <labels>
      <!--label description: the name (if any) of any label you want to see with the subgrid-->
      <label description="Price Level Detail" languagecode="1033" />
    </labels>
    <!--control id: the name of the subgrid
    classid: the type of control (in this case, a subgrid)-->
    <control id="CustomPriceLevelItemSubGrid" classid="{E7A81278-8635-4d9e-8D4D-59480B391C5B}">
      <parameters>
        <!--ViewID: the ID stored in the system for the entity you're interested in (in this case, productpricelevel/Price Level Detail)-->
        <ViewId>{AB4877E9-6D01-4D28-84C3-BE7564C1BB09}</ViewId>
        <IsUserView>false</IsUserView>
        <!--RelationshipName: the name of the relationship that links the two entities (pricelevel to productpricelevel)-->
        <RelationshipName>price_level_product_price_levels</RelationshipName>
        <!--TargetEntityType: the entity you want to see displayed in the subgrid-->
        <TargetEntityType>productpricelevel</TargetEntityType>
        <AutoExpand>Fixed</AutoExpand>
        <EnableQuickFind>true</EnableQuickFind>
        <EnableViewPicker>true</EnableViewPicker>
        <ViewIds></ViewIds>
        <EnableJumpBar>true</EnableJumpBar>
        <ChartGridMode>Grid</ChartGridMode>
        <VisualizationId></VisualizationId>
        <IsUserChart>false</IsUserChart>
        <EnableChartPicker>false</EnableChartPicker>
        <RecordsPerPage>4</RecordsPerPage>
      </parameters>
    </control>
  </cell>
</row>
<row />
<row />
<row />
<row />
<row />
<row />
<row />
```